# IPv4 Restrictions on IIS7 with Shared configuration

Tags: iis, iis-7

On a 2008 R2 server we have shared configuration set and also IPv4 Restrictions, however the restrictions don't seem to work if shared configuration is on.  I have only found this issue elsewhere online at http://forums.iis.net/p/1162818/1977556.aspx (after a considerable time searching).

I was wondering if anyone is able to point me in the direction of anything official to back this up or if anyone has any further information on it.  Or is it just a case of an undocumented "feature" of IIS?!

Answer (score 0):

I read through the link you posted and the answer by 'abadon' at '04-05-2011, 2:49 AM' (EST I assume, per my settings) suggests that it was a configuration issue during the install.  Possibly the installer incorrectly allowed installing feature while shared configuration was enabled.

Did you try uninstalling, turning off shared configuration, installing on the nodes separately, and then re-enabling shared configuration?  According to Abodon's comment, it sounds like he confirmed that it works correctly with shared configuration once he resolved the install issue.

The install issue is probably from one of the nodes not having all dependencies registered correctly.